# MUI v5 Property 'fullWidth' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { theme: Theme; } & { children?: ReactNode; }'. TS2322

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am using MUI v5 and have a simple `FormControl` as below
I know that the property `fullWidth` is valid as outlined in the [documentation](https://mui.com/api/form-control/).

```
import React, { PropsWithChildren } from 'react'
import { Theme } from '@mui/material/styles'
import styled from '@mui/material/styles/styled'
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel'
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem'
import MuiFormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl'

interface SelectProps extends MuiSelectProps {
  id: string
  label?: string
  options?: { text: string; option: string }[]
}

const FormControl: React.FC<{ theme: Theme }> = styled(MuiFormControl)(({ theme }) => ({
  color: theme.palette.nav.links,
  borderRadius: 30,
  width: 180,
}))

export const Select = ({ label, id, children, options }: PropsWithChildren<SelectProps>) => {
  return (
    <FormControl fullWidth hiddenLabel>
        <InputLabel>
          {label}
        </InputLabel>
    </FormControl>
  )
}
```

### TS Error

```
Failed to compile
/var/www/target/component-library/src/components/Select/index.tsx
TypeScript error in /var/www/target/component-library/src/components/Select/index.tsx(24,18):
Type '{ children: ("" | Element | undefined)[]; fullWidth: true; hiddenLabel: true; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { theme: Theme; } & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'fullWidth' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { theme: Theme; } & { children?: ReactNode; }'.  TS2322

    22 | export const Select = ({ label, id, children, options, ...props }: PropsWithChildren<SelectProps>) => {
    23 |   return (
  > 24 |     <FormControl fullWidth hiddenLabel>
       |                  ^
    25 |       {label && (
    26 |         <InputLabel id={`input_${id}`} shrink={false}>
    27 |           {label}
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the type `React.FC<{ theme: Theme }>` when declaring the `FormControl`:

```
const FormControl = styled(MuiFormControl)(...);
```

The resulted component created by the HOC from `styled()` can infer the prop type from the original component like `fullWidth` or `hiddenLabel`, but you assert the type again in your variable. This type:

```
React.FC<{ theme: Theme }>
```

Means a functional component that accepts a prop with the type `{ theme: Theme }`, it doesn't have the `fullWidth` property so Typescript is complaining.

If you want to extend the props type in your custom styled component:

```
const FormControl = styled(MuiFormControl)<{ yourCustomProp?: string }>(...);
```

```
<FormControl yourCustomProp='...' />
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: That last line is super helpful!

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I actually got this point :D However I got stuck on : `Property 'theme' is missing in type '{ children: ("" | Element | undefined)[]; fullWidth: true; hiddenLabel: true; }' but required in type '{ theme: Theme; }'.  TS2741` But I am glad that I asked and it helped others

Comment: @JamieHutber it's because the last line adds `theme` as a required property in `FormControl` in typescript. Just remove it and you'll be fine: `styled(MuiFormControl)(...)`

Comment: @JamieHutber do you still have any problem?